# DBVisualizer query snytax to add a range of values

Tags: dbvisualizer

I need to be able to do something like this in DBVisualizer:

WHERE
  Column = {12, 23, 55, 33, 22}

Instead, I am doing this

WHERE
 Column = 12 OR
 Column = 23 OR
 Column = 55 OR
 Column = 33 OR
 Column = 22

Is there some sort of syntax reserved for this purpose? The latter is very tedious, and I am not a database person. So any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE Column in (12,23,55,33,22)
```

note that this language is not a function of dbvisualizer, but of the database you are connecting to.  The above code works for every RDBMS I've ever worked with.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

I think this wants the SQL tag!